# How to Disable check Boxes in a listview during execution in Vb.net..

Tags: vb.net

In my application i want that when user select one checkbox all other should be disable for him and when he uncheck that checkbox it will delete from listview and other disable should be able for him...
Deletion part have done so kindly guide me for second part

Answer (score 1):

I will enhance @David´s answer:

You have to register the `CheckedChanged` event for your checkboxes, e.g. in the Form´s Load event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     For Each checkbox In Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
         AddHandler checkbox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf Checkbox_CheckedChanged
     Next
End Sub
```

The `Checkbox_CheckedChanged` which handles the event when the user manually clickes a checkbox:

```
Private Sub Checkbox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Checkbox the user manually clicked
    Dim changedCheckbox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)

    If changedCheckbox.Checked Then
        For Each otherCheckbox In Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
            'We don´t want to change the state of the checkbox the user clicked on
            If changedCheckbox IsNot otherCheckbox Then
                otherCheckbox.Checked = False
            End If
        Next
    Else
        'Your part of deleting in listview
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was too late to write my post ahahah

Comment: I was a little confused as to what he meant to be honest, I'm still not entirely sure either, but +1

Answer (score 0):

`Checkbox1_CheckedChange` method is what you need for that.

```
If Checkbox1.Checked = True Then
   Checkbox2.Enabled = False
   Checkbox3.Enabled = False
Else
  Checkbox2.Enabled = True
  Checkbox3.Enabled = True
End If
```

Comment: i want to do it in loop insetad of selected check box all other should be disable

Comment: @UmairNazir What do you mean all other? All other what?

Comment: suppose i have 3 checkbox with some data in listview.. when i will select 1 checkbox other should be disable for me.... when i will uncheck it . it should be removed and other is now able for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is better a function:

```
Public Function DisableCheckBox(ByVal OriginalCheckBox As CheckBox)
    Try
        Dim Parent As Control = OriginalCheckBox.Parent

        For Each Chk As CheckBox In Parent.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
            If Not Chk.Name = OriginalCheckBox.Name Then
                Chk.Enabled = Not Chk.Enabled
            End If
        Next

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Then you can simply call with:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    DisableCheckBox(sender)
End Sub
```